# Does the AR-parameters sum to 1 violate stationarity?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, autoregressive, unit-root

Use AR(2) model as an example of my question:
$$x_t = \phi_1 X_{t-1} + \phi_2 X_{t-2} + \varepsilon_t$$

if $\phi_1 = 0.5$ and $\phi_2 = 0.5$, then sum of AR-parameters equals to 1.

**Does it violate the stationarity(or more precisely stability)?**

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: Try expressing $x_t$ recursively in terms of $x_{-1}, x_0, \varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2, \dots, \varepsilon_t$ to see whether the epsilons enter as a sum $\sum_{\tau=0}^t \varepsilon_\tau$ or not. If they do, the process has a unit root. If they do not, it does not. Start by substituting $x_{t-1}$ on the right hand side according to the model, then substitute $x_{t-2}$ and so on.

Hint 2: Alternatively, try finding the roots of the model's characteristic polynomial. [Characteristic Equation for AR(p) Processes](https://www.real-statistics.com/time-series-analysis/autoregressive-processes/characteristic-equation-autoregressive-processes/) offers a worked out example for AR(2).